# Removing first word using pointers from char array(C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

I need to write a program to remove the first word from a char array (char []) using only pointers. If there are multiple blank spaces in front, I have to ignore them and remove the first word.

These are the loops I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    char sentence[1000];
    std::cout<<"Input sentence: ";
    std::cin.getline(sentence,1000);
    char *p=sentence;
    while(*p==' ' && *p++==' ')
    {
        p++;
    }
    while(*p!=' ')
    {
        p++;
    }
    std::cout<<"Sentence without first word: ";
    while(*p!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<*p;
        p++;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*p is a pointer to char[] (char *p=char int[1000])

When I output the char array later to see if the program is working, it doesn't work properly if the array was an empty array or a one-word array.

Why does *p (pointer to character) print out random signs (chars) instead of nothing, when the array is blank?

Example:

```
Input:       word

Output: #U
```

Full program instead of just loops for editing the array.

Comment: A `for` loop might be better than a `while` loop by the way, as it will be more compact but still as readable.

Comment: So, the task is not to actually remove a word from the array, but to advance a pointer past the first word?

Comment: By the way, why are you using pointers and `new[]` for strings? Why not `std::string`?

Comment: As for random characters and blank spaces: Run it with `valgrind` and you will see.

Comment: @OP *I have to ignore them and remove the first word* -- Note -- you are not removing anything.  All you're really tring to do is change the pointer value to point after the first word.  If you really and truly want to remove the first word, then you would use C++ and `std::string`.

Comment: `*p++==' '` : I'd advise to avoid such expression which are extremely confusing (actually I am not 100% if it is checking the value at p or p+1). And I actually don't understand the purpose of this part, `while(*p==' '){p++;}` is enough to skip leading spaces.

Comment: please  explain what the code is supposed to do (without using the word "pointer")

Comment: And why do you use pointers?  there are std::string, std::string_view, std::vector. e.g. `std::string sentence; std::cin >> sentence;` Then use [std::string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to avoid running past the end if the input string. In general reuse of tested (standard library) code is recommmended.

Comment: that first loop is very odd, it increments p twice for each iteration, effectively looking at every other character. Either way all your loops keep going until they hit a space character, which the input of 'word' does not contain, so it keeps reading random memory till it does hit a space. Hence your random output

Comment: Even if you use pointers, you can still use standard algorithms like `std::find()`, `std::find_first(_not)_of()`, etc instead of manual loops.

Answer (score 2):

Your 1st and 2nd `while` loops don't stop if the null terminator `'\0'` is reached.  So, when the array is empty or contains only 1 word, you are advancing `p` past the null terminator into an uninitialized section of the array, and possibly even beyond the end of the array into surrounding memory.

Also, you should not be doing `p++` inside the 1st loop's condition like you are doing.  Your 1st loop is advancing `p` by two characters per iteration when `*p` is a space character. It should be advancing `p` by only one character per iteration.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char sentence[1000] = {};
    std::cout << "Input sentence: ";
    std::cin.getline(sentence, 1000);

    char *p = sentence;

    // skip leading whitespace before 1st word
    while (*p <= ' ' && *p != '\0') {
        ++p;
    }

    // skip 1st word
    while (*p > ' ') {
        ++p;
    }

    // skip whitespace between 1st and 2nd words
    while (*p <= ' ' && *p != '\0') {
        ++p;
    }

    std::cout << "Sentence without first word: ";
    while (*p != '\0') {
        std::cout << *p;
        ++p;
    }
    // or simply:
    // std::cout << p;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(*p!=' ')
```

The end of a character string is marked by a '`\0'` byte.

Which is not a space.

So, this while loop will happily plow forward, looking for a nonexistent space, resulting in undefined behavior.

This is an example of the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming in force: "Your Computer Always Does Exactly What You Tell It To Do Instead Of What You Want It To Do". You told your computer to not stop the while loop until it sees a `' '`. So that's what your computer does. The end of the string will not stop your computer, from this mission.

You need to check for both the space and a `'\0'`, here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a C question, not a C++ question, and it is important to keep in mind that “traditional” C strings end with a `'\0'` byte. Failing to check for that leads to all sorts of memory access errors.

Here’s a quick and dirty and sloppy implementation that skips the first word of each line on its input while checking for C-string ending bytes properly. Whether the spaces *after* the first word (and not only *before* the first word) should be skipped, that’s easy to adjust.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace {
const char* skip_first_word_c_style(const char* c_str) {
  while (*c_str && *c_str == ' ') ++c_str;  // spaces before first word
  while (*c_str && *c_str != ' ') ++c_str;  // first word
  while (*c_str && *c_str == ' ') ++c_str;  // spaces after first word
  return c_str;
}
}  // namespace

int main() {
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
    std::cout << skip_first_word_c_style(line.c_str()) << std::endl;
  }
}
```